# Azure functions with TS produces no output?

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

I have the following in a typescript file:

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest) {
    context.done(null, {
        body: "Still does not work"
    })
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

when I visit the function url I get a blank page instead of the body.

seems fairly straightforward this should work unless I'm missing something super obvious?

Comment: unfortuantely none of the reasons you've given explains the complete lack of output - it looks like azure functions with typescript ignores the .done function

Comment: I'm aware of what typescript is :) I updated the example with typescript code instead to put you at ease, rest assured context.done still doesn't work so if you have any useful information on that point I'd appreciate it. The reason I had it in javascript was to highlight strongly that the issue appears to be in the azure functions typescript http trigger and not an inherent issue with typescript, because as you correctly pointed out typescript is a superset of javascript it shouldn't matter if the code is javascript or typescript ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of your `context.done` callback is incorrect.
You forgot to add to wrap the output object within a property named `res` or the name you gave to your output binding in the `function.json` file.

```
  {
    "authLevel": null,
    "type": "http",
    "direction": "out",
    "name": "res",
    "methods": null
  }
```

If instead you do:

```
context.done(null, {
      res: {body: "Now it does work"}
    })
```

You should see `Now it does work` in the response